# ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints - on php:7-fpm-alpine

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I'm looking at setting up laravel on an fpm-alpine container.  Running into a snag where the below Dockerfile is producing some errors...

```
FROM php:7-fpm-alpine

# install extensions needed for Laravel
RUN apk --update add \
  php7-mysqli \
  php7-mcrypt \
  php7-mbstring \
  rm /var/cache/apk/*
```

Errors produced are:

```
Building fpm
Step 1 : FROM php:7-fpm-alpine
 ---> 9e6811cb8bac
Step 2 : RUN apk --update add   php7-mysqli   php7-mcrypt   php7-mbstring   rm /var/cache/apk/*
 ---> Running in 87364957eb57
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.3/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.3/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  /var/cache/apk/* (missing):
    required by: world[/var/cache/apk/*]
  php7-mbstring (missing):
    required by: world[php7-mbstring]
  php7-mcrypt (missing):
    required by: world[php7-mcrypt]
  php7-mysqli (missing):
    required by: world[php7-mysqli]
  rm (missing):
    required by: world[rm]
ERROR: Service 'fpm' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apk --update add   php7-mysqli   php7-mcrypt   php7-mbstring   rm /var/cache/apk/*' returned a non-zero code: 5
```

I can search for these package names and [find them on the alpine linux web site](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/testing/x86_64/php7-mcrypt).  Any thoughts on how I can work around this?  It's like it's not updating the apt cache... but adding an LS I can see contents there:

```
Building fpm
Step 1 : FROM php:7-fpm-alpine
 ---> 9e6811cb8bac
Step 2 : RUN apk update
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9ef09f3aa2a2
Step 3 : RUN ls /var/cache/apk
 ---> Running in e126a083a306
APKINDEX.5a59b88b.tar.gz
APKINDEX.7c1f02d6.tar.gz
```

Any ideas on what I can do to resolve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wasn't using `docker-php-ext-install` which is required when adding working within the container...

```
FROM php:7-fpm-alpine

# install extensions needed for Laravel
RUN apk update \
    && apk add libmcrypt-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install mcrypt mysqli pdo_mysql \
    && rm /var/cache/apk/*
```

Comment: Is this actually working? It seems like compiling some of these extensions might need development packages (such as `libmcrypt-dev`).

Comment: Yes indeed it does

Answer (score 13):

Base Docker image probably references an incorrect repository.

Pass over the correct repositories to the `apk add` command like this:

```
RUN apk add --update \
--repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main \
--repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community \
php7-mysqli php7-mcrypt php7-mbstring
```

Answer (score 2):

I met the same error. Solved it by removing the package version from its name:

https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/225#issuecomment-220339154

Comment: Brilliant. Worked like a treat.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same error, and tried the solution here, found the `apk update` is crucial.