# ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints using apk in dockerfile

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, alpine-package-keeper

I'm trying to install postgis into a postgres container.
Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres:9.6.4-alpine

RUN apk update \
    && apk add -u postgresql-9.6-postgis-2.4 postgresql-9.6-postgis-2.4-scripts \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY ./scripts/postgis.sh  /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/postgis.sh
```

postgis.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

for DB in $(psql -t -c  "SELECT datname from pg_database where datname = 'backend'"); do
    echo "Loading PostGIS extensions into $DB"
    "${psql[@]}" --dbname="$DB" <<-'EOSQL'
        CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis;
EOSQL
done
```

I got this error:

> ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
>     postgresql-9.6-postgis-2.4 (missing):
>       required by:
>                    world[postgresql-9.6-postgis-2.4]
>     postgresql-9.6-postgis-2.4-scripts (missing):
>       required by:
>                    world[postgresql-9.6-postgis-2.4-scripts]
>   The command '/bin/sh -c apk update     && apk add -u postgresql-9.6-postgis-2.4 postgresql-9.6-postgis-2.4-scripts     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*' returned a non-zero code: 2

I found similar questions such as :

1. [ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints: while installing package in alpine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48417891/error-unsatisfiable-constraints-while-installing-package-in-alpine)
2. [ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints - on php:7-fpm-alpine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36530620/error-unsatisfiable-constraints-on-php7-fpm-alpine)

But it doesn't solve my problem.How can I add postgis extension to my postgres container with apk?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[Postgis](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/testing/x86_64/postgis) package is only available in edge alpine repo, not in a stable one. That's why you are getting "unsatisfiable constraints" error.

But anyway you can install `postgis` from edge repo:

```
# echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" >> /etc/apk/repositories

# apk update
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.5/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.5/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
WARNING: This apk-tools is OLD! Some packages might not function properly.
v3.5.2-254-g9d4623dc57 [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.5/main]
v3.5.2-247-gc85efb30e1 [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.5/community]
v3.7.0-2163-ge03552fc58 [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing]
OK: 10930 distinct packages available

# apk search --no-cache postgis
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.5/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.5/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
WARNING: This apk-tools is OLD! Some packages might not function properly.
postgis-dev-2.4.1-r1
postgis-2.4.1-r1
postgis-doc-2.4.1-r1
```

So, the final `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM postgres:9.6.4-alpine

RUN echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" >> /etc/apk/repositories

RUN apk update \
    && apk add -u postgis \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY ./scripts/postgis.sh  /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/postgis.sh
```

**UPDATED on January 23th 2020:**

[Postgis](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.11/community/x86_64/postgis) is available in main and community repositories starting from Alpine version 3.11:

```
/ # cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Alpine Linux"
ID=alpine
VERSION_ID=3.11.3
PRETTY_NAME="Alpine Linux v3.11"
HOME_URL="https://alpinelinux.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.alpinelinux.org/"
/ #
/ # apk search --no-cache postgis
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
postgis-3.0.0-r1
postgis-doc-3.0.0-r1
```

You don't need to use edge repo testing branch for Alpine version 3.11 and later.

Comment: I get the following error when following your instructions: `postgis (missing): ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints: required by: world[postgis]`. I used the following command: `echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" >> /etc/apk/repositories && apk update && apk add -u postgis && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`

Comment: I also tried to install PostGIS directly on an Alpine image, but stumbled upon a similar issue. I posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59882544/error-unsatisfiable-constraints-when-installing-postgis-on-the-alpine-docker-im) about it. I appreciate if you could help.

Comment: @mhyousefi I've updated my answer. Some changes have been done in Alpine world since I answered the question.

Answer (score 6):

Old:

```
apk add --no-cache curl jq python py-pip
```

New:

```
apk add --no-cache curl jq python3 py3-pip
```

Answer (score -1):

It is weird but in my case solution was as simple as to run:

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

... on a machine where you running docker containers