# Cant use PostGIS on Alpine image

Tags: postgresql, docker, postgis, alpine-linux

I'm trying to use the `Alpine` image to take care of some `Postgres` db creation/preparation.
Inside the container, I am running the following commands:

```
createdb -e -O ${DB_USER} ${DB_NAME}
psql -e -d ${DB_NAME} -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"
```

The first line works fine, but the second does NOT.

I have tried this with two docker builds:

1. The following Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.6

RUN apk add -U postgresql

COPY ./db-creator.sh /db-creator.sh
CMD ["./db-creator.sh"]
```

This image gives me the following error:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
```

I didn't try to install `PostGIS` directly as someone in [this forum](https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/issues/7772) insisted that `apk add -U postgresql` on a bare `Alpine` image should suffice.

2. The following Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres:9.6.4-alpine

RUN apk add -U postgresql
RUN echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" >> /etc/apk/repositories
RUN apk update && apk add -u postgis

COPY ./db-creator.sh /db-creator.sh
CMD ["./db-creator.sh"]
```

I added the last two RUN statements to follow what was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48892448/error-unsatisfiable-constraints-using-apk-in-dockerfile). In this case, I am unable to directly install `PostGIS` and get the following error:

```
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.6/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.6/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
WARNING: This apk-tools is OLD! Some packages might not function properly.
v3.6.5-44-gda55e27396 [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.6/main]
v3.6.5-34-gf0ba0b43d5 [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.6/community]
v20200117-229-g073aaff70d [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing]
OK: 12520 distinct packages available
WARNING: This apk-tools is OLD! Some packages might not function properly.
  postgis (missing):
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
    required by: world[postgis]
```

How on earth :)), can I use `PostGIS` with the `Alpine` image? Do I need to use other image versions or install `PostGIS` differently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres), Additional Extensions section:

> When using the Alpine variants, any postgres extension not listed in
>   postgres-contrib will need to be compiled in your own image (again,
>   see github.com/appropriate/docker-postgis for a concrete example).

For debian based here is the docker image:

https://github.com/appropriate/docker-postgis/blob/f6d28e4a1871b1f72e1c893ff103f10b6d7cb6e1/10-2.4/Dockerfile

If you want to bundle Postgis with PostgreSQL Alpine image you have build it.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I followed your advice but I'm having trouble installing PostGIS manually. I have created another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59882544/error-unsatisfiable-constraints-when-installing-postgis-on-the-alpine-docker-im). I appreciate if you could help.

Comment: @mhyousefi will check it once I have time.