# ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints when installing PostGIS on the Alpine Docker image

Tags: postgresql, docker, postgis, alpine-linux

Ok, so the task seems pretty easy! Use an `Alpine` image (as it is light-weight and secure) to perform some `PostgreSQL` DB creation/migrations. I'm using the following `Dockerfile` using the code [here](https://github.com/appropriate/docker-postgis/blob/master/11-2.5/alpine/Dockerfile):

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk add -U postgresql

# install PostGIS
ENV POSTGIS_VERSION 2.5.2
ENV POSTGIS_SHA256 225aeaece00a1a6a9af15526af81bef2af27f4c198de820af1367a792ee1d1a9
RUN set -ex \
    \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .fetch-deps \
        ca-certificates \
        openssl \
        tar \
    \
    && wget -O postgis.tar.gz "https://github.com/postgis/postgis/archive/$POSTGIS_VERSION.tar.gz" \
    && echo "$POSTGIS_SHA256 *postgis.tar.gz" | sha256sum -c - \
    && mkdir -p /usr/src/postgis \
    && tar \
        --extract \
        --file postgis.tar.gz \
        --directory /usr/src/postgis \
        --strip-components 1 \
    && rm postgis.tar.gz \
    \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
        autoconf \
        automake \
        g++ \
        json-c-dev \
        libtool \
        libxml2-dev \
        make \
        perl \
    \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps-edge \
        --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing \
        --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main \
        gdal-dev \
        geos-dev \
        proj4-dev \
        protobuf-c-dev \
    && cd /usr/src/postgis \
    && ./autogen.sh \
# configure options taken from:
# https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-grass/postgis.git/tree/debian/rules?h=jessie
    && ./configure \
#       --with-gui \
    && make \
    && make install \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .postgis-rundeps \
        json-c \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .postgis-rundeps-edge \
        --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing \
        --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main \
        geos \
        gdal \
        proj4 \
        protobuf-c \
    && cd / \
    && rm -rf /usr/src/postgis \
    && apk del .fetch-deps .build-deps .build-deps-edge

COPY ./db-creator.sh /db-creator.sh
CMD ["./db-creator.sh"]
```

However, the dependencies are not installed using `apk` due to some `unsatisfiable constraints` error. The error is as follows and the full logs are available in [this issue](https://github.com/appropriate/docker-postgis/issues/163) I opened.

```
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  gdal-dev (missing):
    required by: .build-deps-edge-20200123.143501[gdal-dev]
  geos-dev (missing):
    required by: .build-deps-edge-20200123.143501[geos-dev]
  proj4-dev (missing):
    required by: .build-deps-edge-20200123.143501[proj4-dev]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code on github contains another image [postgres:11-alpine](https://github.com/appropriate/docker-postgis/blob/master/11-2.5/alpine/Dockerfile#L1) comparing  to image defined in question: `alpine:latest`.

Packages [gdal-dev](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.11/community/x86_64/gdal-dev), [geos-dev](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.11/community/x86_64/geos-dev), [protobuf-c-dev](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.11/main/x86_64/protobuf-c-dev) are no longer in edge repo testing branch, they were migrated to stable v3.11 repository. Also `proj4-dev` was renamed to [proj-dev](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.11/community/x86_64/proj-dev), which is also in stable v3.11 repository.

So to fix the `Dockerfile` we just need to install above packages from v3.11 repo, ie change this part of code:

```
&& apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
    autoconf \
    automake \
    g++ \
    json-c-dev \
    libtool \
    libxml2-dev \
    make \
    perl \
\
&& apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps-edge \
    --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing \
    --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main \
    gdal-dev \
    geos-dev \
    proj4-dev \
    protobuf-c-dev \
    proj4-dev \
    protobuf-c-dev \
```

to this one:

```
&& apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
    autoconf \
    automake \
    g++ \
    gdal-dev \
    geos-dev \
    json-c-dev \
    libtool \
    libxml2-dev \
    make \
    perl \
    proj-dev \
    protobuf-c-dev \
\
```

The final `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM alpine:3.11

RUN apk add -U postgresql

# install PostGIS
ENV POSTGIS_VERSION 2.5.2
ENV POSTGIS_SHA256 225aeaece00a1a6a9af15526af81bef2af27f4c198de820af1367a792ee1d1a9
RUN set -ex \
    \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .fetch-deps \
        ca-certificates \
        openssl \
        tar \
    \
    && wget -O postgis.tar.gz "https://github.com/postgis/postgis/archive/$POSTGIS_VERSION.tar.gz" \
    && echo "$POSTGIS_SHA256 *postgis.tar.gz" | sha256sum -c - \
    && mkdir -p /usr/src/postgis \
    && tar \
        --extract \
        --file postgis.tar.gz \
        --directory /usr/src/postgis \
        --strip-components 1 \
    && rm postgis.tar.gz \
    \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
        autoconf \
        automake \
        g++ \
        gdal-dev \
        geos-dev \
        json-c-dev \
        libtool \
        libxml2-dev \
        make \
        perl \
        proj-dev \
        protobuf-c-dev \
    \
    && cd /usr/src/postgis \
    && ./autogen.sh \
# configure options taken from:
# https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-grass/postgis.git/tree/debian/rules?h=jessie
    && ./configure \
#       --with-gui \
    && make \
    && make install \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .postgis-rundeps \
        json-c \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .postgis-rundeps-edge \
        --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing \
        --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main \
        geos \
        gdal \
        proj4 \
        protobuf-c \
    && cd / \
    && rm -rf /usr/src/postgis \
    && apk del .fetch-deps .build-deps .build-deps-edge

COPY ./db-creator.sh /db-creator.sh
CMD ["./db-creator.sh"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. There is an error on configure:

+ apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps-edge --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main gdal-dev geos-dev proj4-dev protobuf-c-dev

ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  gdal-dev (missing):
    required by: .build-deps-edge-20200124.075938[gdal-dev]
  geos-dev (missing):
    required by: .build-deps-edge-20200124.075938[geos-dev]
  proj4-dev (missing):
    required by: .build-deps-edge-20200124.075938[proj4-dev]

Comment: Thank you very much @Nickolay for your elaborate help! It is worth mentioning that the `./configure` command fails as the Dockerfile above, as is, does not have a `pg_config`. Any suggestions on how to do it other than running starting a Postgres server (e.g. by setting some ENVs)?